# How to use Basic authentication for web browser requests with ServiceStack?

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I have a REST API built using ServiceStack. I am using BasicAuthentication without any issues when calling the REST APIs (I am registering the `AuthFeature` with the `BasicAuthProvider`).

Now I am trying to build some HTML management pages. These should also be authenticated.

The [Authenticate] attribute redirects to the /login page, so I created the following DTO and matching service to handle logins:

```
    [DefaultView("Login")]
    public class SiteLoginService : EnshareServiceBase
    {
        public object Get(SiteLoginRequest req)
        {
            return new SiteLoginRequest();
        }

        public object Post(SiteLoginRequest req)
        {
            //I am trying to use the registered IAuthProvider, which is the BasicAuthProvider
            var authProvider = ResolveService<IAuthProvider>();
            authProvider.Authenticate(this, EnshareSession,
                                      new ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth()
                                      {
                                          Password = req.Password,
                                          UserName = req.UserName
                                      });
            return HttpResult.Redirect(req.Redirect);
        }
    }

    [Route("/login")]
    public class SiteLoginRequest : IReturn<SiteLoginRequest>
    {
        public string Redirect { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

However, the BasicAuthProvider always throws HttpError: "Invalid BasicAuth credentials" when I fill in username and password on the Login view page and POST these to the SiteLoginService. It is probably because the web browser is not filling in the Basic auth header, but I do not know how to authenticate with filled in username and password.

**How to properly authenticate site users against the AuthProvider which works with the existing REST API?**

Comment: Have you included the `new BasicAuthProvider()` when you registered your **AuthFeature**?

Comment: Originally I included just my CustomAuthProvider inherited from BasicAuthProvider. The solution was to include also CredentialsAuthProvider - I posted my own answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured I need to include also the CredentialsAuthProvider in the AuthFeature, which will expose /auth/credentials service which I form post a form to.

```
        //this inherits the BasicAuthProvider and is used to authenticate the REST API calls
        var myCustomAuthProvider = new CustomAuthProvider(appSettings);
        var credentialsProvider = new CredentialsAuthProvider(appSettings);
        container.Register<IAuthProvider>(myCustomAuthProvider);
        container.Register<CredentialsAuthProvider>(credentialsProvider);
        var authFeature = new AuthFeature(() => new EnshareSession(new MongoTenantRepository()),
                                          new IAuthProvider[] {
                                                                  myCustomAuthProvider,
                                                                  credentialsProvider 
                                                               })
```

So I specified the action in my login form as /auth/credentials, while providing the required UserName and Password fields.

```
        <form action="/auth/credentials" method="post">
            <p class="entryfield">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, "Login name:")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserName)
            </p>
            <p class="entryfield">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            </p>
            <input class="formbutton" type="submit" value="Login" />
        </form>
```

When the form is posted, it hits the authentication code flows properly (`TryAuthenticate` is called in my `IUserAuthRepository` and returns true).

Ultimately the request receives a 302 and my login form at /login is redisplayed.

```
    HTTP/1.1 302 Found
    Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
    Date: Wed, 30 Oct 2013 08:15:54 GMT
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3,969 Win32NT/.NET
    Location: http://localhost:64944/login?redirect=%2fadmin
    Set-Cookie: X-UAId=3; expires=Sun, 30-Oct-2033 08:15:54 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
```

It is setting the session cookie (X-AUId) and the user is properly authenticated. Subsequent web browser requests to Services decorated with the Authenticate attribute succeed.

So the only missing part is how to ensure that the user is properly redirected after posting to `/auth/credentials`.

To ensure the redirection works, a quick look at the has shown that a Continue parameter is expected.

So this is how the login form needs to look like (I reused the Auth class from ServiceStack for the model):

```
    @inherits ViewPage<ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth>
    @{

        Layout = "AdminLayout";
    }

    <form action="/auth/credentials" method="post">
        <p class="entryfield">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, "Login name:")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserName)
        </p>
        <p class="entryfield">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
        </p>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Continue)
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
```

The Continue property is populated in the service from the Redirect property of its model.

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing the Username & Password as a post, then as you suspect you are not doing Basic Authentication.

[This article](http://www.peej.co.uk/articles/http-auth-with-html-forms.html) explains how to do basic authentication with JavaScript.  From the article:

```
function login() {
    var username = document.getElementById(this.id + "-username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById(this.id + "-password").value;
    this.http.open("get", this.action, false, username, password);
    this.http.send("");
    if (http.status == 200) {
        document.location = this.action;
     } else {
        alert("Incorrect username and/or password.");
    }
    return false;
}
```

ServiceStack also supports other forms of authentication including sending a username and password via a POST if that is what you want.  If you explain your requirements we can give some recommendations.

Comment: I do not want to use javascript for authentication. I want to do a normal http post from html form.